# Rsyslog, exclude logs

Tags: logging, rsyslog

i have a custom daemon that gives logs to rsyslog facility "local1" with two security levels - "info" and "debug". I need to write "info" logs to /var/log/info and "debug" logs to /var/log/debug.

I edited rsyslog.conf

```
local1.*;local1.debug       /var/log/info.log

local1.debug                /var/log/debug.log
```

When daemon gives "info" logs it works well, it writes to info.log and debug.log is empty.
But when i get "debug" logs it writes to both files.

Help me to exclude debug logs from info.log.

`;local1.=debug` not working.
 I also tried to write

```
local1.!debug /var/log/info.log
```

But still not working (in this config info logs is empty)

rsyslog 8.24.0-12

Centos 7.4

**UPDATE**

```
local1.info                     /var/log/info.log
local1.debug;local1.info        /var/log/debug.log
```

Not working too, info goes to info.log, it's ok. But in debug.log there is info+debug, and i can't exclude info from it. `;local1.info` not working

Comment: Have you tried `local1.info /var/log/info.log` instad of `local1.debug /var/log/info.log`? Looks like a typo. The star * will include everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is in the man page:

> The  behavior  of  the  original  BSD syslogd is that all messages of
>   the specified priority and higher are logged according to the given
>   action. Rsyslogd behaves the same, but has some extensions.

So if you want to exclude debug, just state the next highest priority, which is info:

```
local1.info       /var/log/info.log
```

This will mean that all messages of priority info and higher will go to /var/log/info.log.

For the debug log, the solution is also in the man page:

> You may precede every  priority  with  an  equals  sign ('=')  to specify only this single priority and not any of the above.

So that line should read

```
local1.=debug       /var/log/debug.log
```

to get only debug messages.

Comment: But if i do this situation will be opposite. i will got info at info logs and debug+info at debug.log

Comment: Updated main post

Comment: @user511890 Updated answer